# NextJS + Redux Persist not render html in source SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using `ReactJS/NextJS` + `Redux` + `redux-persist` also `Ant Design`, today I noticed my `html` codes or other data not render in page's source, it render in browser and also in inspect element but not in source <kbd>ctrl+u</kbd>.

Little confused because I used `nextjs` because it's SSR, but now it acting like CSR, googled but not found right solution to fix this, I share my code:

**store/index.js:**

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import reducers from "../reducers";
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers)

export const store = createStore(persistedReducer);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

**_app.js:**

```
import { store, persistor } from "../redux/store";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <ConfigProvider
          theme={{
          algorithm: theme.defaultAlgorithm,
            token:
                { fontFamily: "DrSalvador",
                  colorPrimary: "#f44"
                }
      }}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ConfigProvider>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>

}
```

**index.js**

```
export default function Home(props) {
     return (<div>//render data</div>)
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
// api requests
}
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Redux is CSR. I think thats why...

Comment: @SayedulKarim Do not make OP confuse by your wrong comment! Redux not CSR not even SSR! Redux itself is not inherently tied to either client-side rendering (CSR) or server-side rendering (SSR),  Whether application uses CSR or SSR depends on how set up React application and how you render components.

Comment: @Pedram okay. Sorry if I say anything wrong. If redux is not CSR or SSR then when setting up the (store) redux on nextjs, why do we use "use client" on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `redux-persist` and replace it with `next-persist`

**[Next-Persist](https://github.com/oslabs-beta/next-persist)**

> next-persist provides a simple solution for your dynamic, isomorphic
> web applications. Just import next-persist, set up a quick config and
> incorporate our functions. We do the rest, delivering you the benefits
> of server side rendering and persistent client data.

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistWrapper wrapperConfig={npConfig}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </PersistWrapper>
      </Provider>
    );
  };
```

---

## Update

If someone any trouble with `next-persist` here is another solution to make your own persist without any package:

### Store.js

```
import reducers from "../reducers";
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
```

### saveStateToLocalStorage

```
export const saveStateToLocalStorage = (state) => {
    try {
        const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
        localStorage.setItem('persist:root', serializedState);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving state to localStorage:', error);
    }
};
```

### loadStateFromLocalStorage

```
export const loadStateFromLocalStorage = () => {
    try {
        const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('persist:root');
        if (serializedState === null) {
            return undefined;
        }
        return JSON.parse(serializedState);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error loading state from localStorage:', error);
        return undefined;
    }
};

const preloadedState = loadStateFromLocalStorage();

    export const store = configureStore({
        reducer: reducers,
        preloadedState: preloadedState,
    });
```